# Python 3 change keys in many dictionaries, efficiency

Tags: python, dictionary, key, rename

I have many dictionaries where the integer keys need to be changed, currently my method of doing this is (below is a very basic example):

```
l = [{3: "x1", 5: "x2", 6:"x3"} for i in range(3)]
keys_to_change = [5,6]

for d in l:
    for k in keys_to_change:
        d[k - 1] = d.pop(k)
```

The starting keys were [3,5,6] they were changed to [3,4,5] in all the dictionaries, maintaining the values behind the keys.

My question is: is this the best way of doing this? Should I think of some of way of storing the data that avoids renaming of dictionary keys in this manner?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem is there some way to do this with a dict comprehension for each dictionary perhaps? or should I think of another way of storing the data?

Comment: What do you want to happen if `d = {0: 'zero', 1: 'one'}` and `keys_to_change = [1]` ?

Comment: @new_to_coding Yes, but he's asking what should happen if that causes duplicate keys in the dictionary.

Comment: @wim o I see, sorry, that's not a concern because it's impossible in my program

Comment: Then the way you have already is fine.

Comment: At some point, you're going to have something like `keys_to_change = [6, 5]` instead of `[5, 6]` and you're going to wonder why your code is assigning the same value to both new keys.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks for your concern but I sort the keys before using them, I haven't shown that here sorry

Comment: You can't sort dict keys. Unless it's an ordereddict, in that case it's a different data structure and quite significant to what answers you might receive. :)